# create form fields on the fly from drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, coffeescript

I dint even understand how to search for my problem scenario in google.

Problem : When a user selects from a drop-down, the below form fields should change accordingly.

Example : If a user selects "Human" from Drop-down , then below form_fields should be shown like "age" field ,"ethnicity" field etc..

If a user selects "Event" from drop-down, below form fields should show "Date", "venue" etc..

and By default we will have "SUBMIT" button.

Can anyone tell how to achieve this ? Any help with simple_form ruby gem also would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to achieve with the `simple_form` gem and some simple javascript.

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :attribute_name, :collection => ['Human', 'Event'], :input_html => { :class => 'dropdown' %>

  <div class="toggle human" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :age %>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle event" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

The key here is wrapping the fields you want to toggle in `div` with specific selectors.

Then we look for a change event on the dropdown field, and toggle our `div`s accordingly.

**Javascript**

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
  // hide divs first
  $('form .toggle').hide();

  // get value from dropdown
  var divClass = $('.dropdown').val().toLowerCase();

  // show necessary div
  $('.' + divClass).show();
});
```

Using this approach, you don't need to write the specific case for every value of the dropdown, but can use the lower case value of the dropdown as the selector for the `div`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BmnA5/) is a simple example with static markup.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to keep the javascript in rails to make use of dynamism ? As I am being a newbie to rails , I don't know where to put javascript such that it my view can use it. Just to let you know i am using coffee-script and jquery rails ..

Comment: i tried pasting your javascript code in assets/javascripts/ and tried to use it from view using "javascript_include_tag" helper ..but could not get it

Comment: You're on the right track. To add javascript to rails you want `javascript_include_tag` before you close `</body>`. Point that to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. And then in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` you can include jquery and other js files. I suggest perusing [this page](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) for a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you tell me what is $("form .toggle)" do ?

Comment: `$("form .toggle")` selects all elements with a class of `toggle` (period is the class selector) contained within a `form` element (generic elements are targeted without a selector -- i.e. no period).

Comment: oh.. so when we are using "form", it means when using inside the form ? or we would use only $('.toggle') right ?

Comment: can you please look at link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211890/dropdown-in-jquery-producing-dynamic-fields` which i am having probelm while implementing with ur code

Comment: Correct. The `form` selector is a nice-to-have in this case because it won't hide other elements on the page if you happen to forget and apply a `toggle` class to a `div` outside the form.

Comment: Hi Davis, i dont know why its not working for me ...can you help please

Comment: Did you check out [my answer on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22212319/2241124)?

Comment: Hi Davis, problem is solved ..thanks for the help..basically it was due to naming dropdown as 'dropdown'( which might be a keyword)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some simple javascript. Lets say you have a form with the following fields

```
<%= f.select :some_field, %w[Human Cat], {}, {:class => 'my-select'}  %>

<div class="human">
  <%= f.label :age %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>
</div>

<div class="cat" style="display:none;">
  <%= f.label :sub_species %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :sub_species %>
</div>
```

Now add some javascript to make it dynamic

```
<script>
  $(".my-select").change(function(){
if($(".my-select").val() == "Human"){
  $(".human").css('display', 'block');
  $(".cat").css('display', 'none');
}else{
  $(".human").css('display','none');
  $(".cat").css('display', 'block');
}
  })
</script>
```