# Dropdown in Jquery producing dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically i want to generate form fields dynamically based on the selection made in dropdown. I have this below code in my view.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "hive" %>

<%= simple_form_for(@obj :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :reason, :collection => ['Human', 'Event'], :input_html => { :class => 'dropdown'} %>

  <div class="toggle human" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="toggle event" style="display:none;">
    <%= f.input :date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Now I have below code in assets/javascript/hive.js

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
  // hide divs first
  $('form .toggle').hide();

  // get value from dropdown
  var divClass = $('.dropdown').val().toLowerCase();

  alert(divClass);

  // show necessary div
  $('.' + divClass).show();
});
```

Everything looks fine to me ..but somehow its not working..Any help is apreciated

Comment: what part isn't working?

Comment: javascript is not working ..like it is not showing any form field based on the selection from dropdown

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: With your JS include tag above your DOM elements it's going to try to attach the event handler before the element has loaded. You should either move the include tag below the HTML or wrap anything in hive.js inside $(document).ready(...).

Comment: I tried both the ways but nothing is happening

Comment: or testiing purpose whether jquery is being called or not ..i tested with this code and the alert value is printing 'ZERO' instead of printing dropdown value ..help $(document).ready(function(){ $('.dropdown').change(function() { var rahul = $('.dropdown').val(); alert(rahul); }); });

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<%= simple_form_for(@obj :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= simple_form_for(@obj, :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
```

Note the `,` after @obj. This should give you first error.

Second, load the javascript after the form `<% end %>`. The reason for doing this is that `.dropdown` element should be existing before calling any action on it.

**EDIT**

Check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4FQ7/). 
Also, make sure that `jQuery` library is included in your generated HTML. 
When the view is rendered in browser, right click and do `View Source`, check if you see a `script` tag with src `jQuery.js`.

Comment: What is the output? Did you place the javascript_include_tag after the form end?

Comment: yes i placed ...output is simply ..dropdown is not responding to jquery.

Comment: do we have to change any priority or something in any place ?

Comment: i implemented the same code i a new rails ap and its workiing fine ....does this thing have any effect on the table column we are using ?

Comment: for testiing purpose whether jquery is being called or not ..i tested with this code and the alert value is printing 'ZERO' instead of printing dropdown value ..help  $(document).ready(function(){
 
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
 
 var rahul = $('.dropdown').val();
 alert(rahul); 
 
 
});
});

Comment: I have updated my answer with JSFiddle. Check that out.

Comment: hmmm no luck kirti.. basically when i am using only alert with change function for dropdown ..its working..but when this code is kept again its not working...i guess its not problem with calling jquery but something else...i have bootstrap..does that make any difference ?

Comment: Are you using the exact code given in the question? If not, update the question with the real code. Also, I recommend clearing browser cache and test the code on multiple browsers. Run my JSFiddle it works with or without alert, so yours should also work.

Comment: I have used your code and its the exact code i have given to you..dont konw whats going wrong..one quick question..does having jquery-rails gem makes it different to access .js files ..or its the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you having at least two potential issues here.

**Load jQuery**

First, you are using jQuery in the javascript file. Since you are loading `hive.js` directly, you need to ensure the jQuery library is also loaded.

The best way to prevent issues here is to add:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "hive" %>
```

to just above the closing `</body>` tag in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Then, within `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, you would include:

```
//= require jquery
//= require hive
```

This means you'll probably want a catch within the javascript file to ensure the code runs if the elements are available (more on this below).

**Wait To Bind The Event**

Second, even if jQuery is loaded, you don't want to bind the event handler until the content exists on the page. There is a possibility this javascript looks to bind a change event to `$('.dropdown')` before that element actually exists on the page.

To solve this, I would force the javascript to wait until the page is loaded to run. Combining this idea with ensuring the content is there gives us something like this for `app/assets/javascripts/hive.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if( $('.dropdown').length > 0 ) {
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
      // hide divs first
      $('form .toggle').hide();

      // get value from dropdown
      var divClass = $('.dropdown').val().toLowerCase();

      alert(divClass);

      // show necessary div
      $('.' + divClass).show();
    });
  }
});
```

**Warning**

And last, because careful about using `<%= javascript_include_tag %>` freely. Whenever you use this directly, you need to add the file to `config/production.rb` to ensure it's compiled for production. Otherwise it will be missing when you deploy and cause errors.

This can quickly become a hassle. In rails, `application.js` is automatically precompiled. This is why it's much, much easier to use `application.js` as a javascript manifest file, and then use checks like `$('.dropdown').length > 0` to know whether or not to run the javascript code. That can quickly get messy, too, but it's much easier to deploy the app.